# Excel Solver VBA: Condition Value "1" not taken

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I have a tricky issue with running the excel solver with VBA. I have a value which should get minimized through equations with changing input parameters within certain ranges. Solver conditions are used to define those allowed ranges the input parameters can vary in. The problem is when the condition value is "1" the condition is not taken by the solver. The condition formula is not added to the solver.
When I change the value to 0.999999 the condition formula is taken by the solver.

Any idea what the problem is? I couldn't find any information about not using the value "1" for conditions.

example:

```
' input value in "C4" must be >= 1
SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("C4"), relation:=3, formulaText:=1
' --> does not work

' input value in "C4" must be >= 0.999
SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("C4"), relation:=3, formulaText:=0.999
' --> works
```

Comment: @pnuts, what do you mean? I do not define any constraints behavior.

Comment: How did you conclude that the value is not taken into account? Did `SolverSolve` return a value in `C4` that was < 1? Can you show us the full code?

Comment: @loannis, indeed the value in `C4` becomes smaller than 1. When I stop the VBA code right after the `SolverAdd` function and go to the Solver menu (data --> solver) there is no condition in the respective condition field. So, the `SolverAdd`function was just ignored.

Comment: As it stands, the problem is not reproducible. I tried to step through the code and check the solver box after the `SolverAdd` but the solver box is not accessible (I am getting an error message `Cant execute code in break mode` using Excel 2010). Could you post more code?

Comment: @loannis, you need to go through the code stepwise and stop the macro after the `SolverAdd` line. The solver box is not accessible when the macro is still active. Give me some minutes for the code...

Answer (score 1):

Add "1" in one cell (e.g E9) and set FormulaText="$E$9". This is how I managed to solve a problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonhtra, did you face the same issue or am I alone?

Comment: I had the same issue, but I think problem was related to Excel on MacOS

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by using the following format:

```
    , FormulaText:= "=" & variable
```

So if variable = 1, then it would be the same as entering:

```
    , FormulaText:= "=1"
```